# Magento 2.3: Copy base,small,thumbnail image from store view to store view with SQL

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, database

In a particular store view, some products doesn't have set the base, small and thumbnail image. I want to set this base image from one store view to another via SQL.

How to do that?